# NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/login

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to use ajax, json for first time and i'm facing the 404 error.
The problem depicts that /login is not found though  i've defined LoginServlet with url pattern /login in web.xml. Below is the code of web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.login.LoginServlet</servlet-class>

  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Below is the code for login.js

```
function Login(){
    console.log("in login function");
    var userId=$('#username').val();
    var pass=$('#password').val();

    if(userId=="" || pass==""){
        alert("UserId or Password cannot be blank!");
        document.getElementById("username").focus();
    }else{
        var url='/login';
        var dataString= 'action=login&userId='+userId+'&pass='+pass;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: dataString,
            success: function (data){
                var loggedIn=data.html();
                console.log(loggedIn + " " + data);
                $('#loggedIn').val(loggedIn);
                $('#loggedIn').show();
            }
            });
    }
```

I've used service method in LoginServlet instead of doGet() and doPost().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess u are trying to access `login` servlet within a web application, hence it should be `http://localhost:8080/webApp/login` right? Since you are trying to access `localhost:8080/login` you are getting the 404 error.

You should change url in the ajax call to `login` instead of `/login`. Also try to access the url in a normal browser window and see what reply you are getting..

Answer (score 0):

Try `http://localhost/{web-app-name}/login`

Generally, the web-app directory is where the code gets deployed.
Also, check if the port entered is correct.

Comment: Is there any way i can use it without giving web-app directory name.

Comment: yes, it's also working with web-app directory name and also with removing the / before login.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see the url directly first, just to check it's working? Also, try a simple HTML form first, no Ajax, plain HTML, just to check your result when you post to that url.

Answer (score 0):

I do it without `/` in my applications.

Try

```
var url='login';
```